# NSWindow restored frame location

Tags: macos, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

On OS X is it possible to programmatically access the restored window location of a zoomed or maximized window.

ie: in most OS X apps you can double click the title bar to zoom it.  If you double click it again it restores it to it's previous position.

I'd like to be able to get and set that saved position rectangle.

Comment: What have you tried? There are a bunch of ways you could do this (NSUserDefaults, Applescript, grab it from com.apple.finder.plist, etc.). Also, how are you planning to trigger the saving of the bounds, and which position are you wanting, the zoomed in or zoomed out?

Comment: @l'L'l We'll I've looked at the docs for NSWindow and NSWindowController.  (NSUserDefaults, Applescript and plist stuff doesn't make sense in this context).  I have an NSWindow that my app created - I want the non-zoomed, non-maximized position (that OS X obviously has somewhere) but cant find an API for it.

Comment: The standard and likely most efficient way would be to use `setFrameAutosaveName`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SavingWindowPosition.html

Comment: @l'L'l Except that I need more finely grained control than that. (eg: I'm trying to manage multiple user switchable window layouts).  Also, that approach doesn't seem to save the restored position anyway.

Comment: What do you mean "restored position", It saves the position - I know that... since I've used it for years.

Comment: @l'L'l Sorry, perhaps my background in Windows programming causing me to cross terms.  By "restored position" I mean the non-maximized/non-zoomed position.  The position that OS X resets the window to when you unzoom/unmaximize it.  When an NSWindow is maximized/zoomed, somewhere OS X keeps a copy of the old frame position - how do I get that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `NSWindowDelegate` to save the `NSWindow` frame just before it's maximized:

```cpp
@interface MyWindowDelegate : NSObject {
@private
  NSRect m_maximizedFrame;
  NSRect m_restoredFrame;
}

- (NSRect)windowWillUseStandardFrame:(NSWindow*)window
                        defaultFrame:(NSRect)newFrame
{
  // Save the expected frame when the window is maximized
  m_maximizedFrame = newFrame;
  return newFrame;
}

- (BOOL)windowShouldZoom:(NSWindow*)window
                 toFrame:(NSRect)newFrame
{
  // The NSWindow is going to be maximized...
  if (NSEqualRects(newFrame, m_maximizedFrame)) {
    // Save the frame before it's maximized
    m_restoredFrame = [window frame];
  }
  return YES;
}
@end
```

The `m_restoredFrame` will be valid only if the window is not resized after that (i.e. `[window isZoomed]` must be true). I'm not sure if there is a better way.